# Ionic 2 app not installing @ionic-native/network

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to use [cordova-plugin-network-information and @ionic-native/network](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/) in my ionic 2 app. However, I get the following error when trying to execute npm install --save @ionic-native/network.

```
npm WARN @ionic-native/network@3.8.1 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ionic-native/network@3.8.1 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
```

How do I fix this? Do I need to upgrade to ionic 3?

Comment: `npm install rxjs -g` and `npm install @ionic-native/core --save`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install ionic native 3.x. Seems you are using ionic native 2.x. please update your package.json. It should work. if I am not mistaken, the latest version is 3.6.1. please follow below guide for more details. Kindly note that it require quite some changes to migrate to ionic native 3.x but thing is you get to mock them which is supported in the browser.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/blob/master/README.md

Ashley

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time we see warnings in our projects. However, these should not affect your application. But, as Ashley suggested, update your application to the latest version to ensure everything is working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Please use as  root/admin if on ubuntu try this

```
    sudo npm install
```

if on windows

open cmd as administrator